# CodeIgniter 4's getBody() and getJSON() Methods

Tags: php, json, php-curl, codeigniter-4

I've come across something puzzling regarding the `getBody()` and `getJSON()` methods when dealing with API responses.

When I use `getBody()`, I get a clean JSON string like this:

Copy code

> "{ "userId": 1, "id": 1, "title": "delectus aut autem", "completed": false }"

However, when I use `getJSON()`, the JSON string looks a bit messy with extra quotes and escape characters:

> ""{\n "userId": 1,\n "id": 1,\n "title": "delectus aut autem",\n "completed": false\n}""

I'm wondering why these differences exist and if there's a preferred method in regular scenarios. Can someone help explain these discrepancies in a way that's easy to understand for someone relatively new to CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your Output strings, the method you used is correct, the difference is Your getBody() function always returns raw string format, while getJSON() function returns processed JSON string.

Both methods have different approaches for processing the response string. You can choose as per your requirement, like how you are getting responses from API endpoint.

Comment: When I do **json_deocode($json, true)** to get the getBody() output I can directly get an array, when doing the same for getJSON() I have to decode twice to get the same output, if I decode once it will produce JSON.

Is it like if I want to work with arrays then use getBody() and if I want to always use JSON can use getJSON?

Comment: That's correct, it's good if you use getJSON() as its a better approach in handling JSON strings.